# Stop Scroll Acceleration when Fingers Land on Touchpad

Tags: gnome, touchpad

So you know how on certain GTK applications (like nautilus, GNOME Tweaks, etc), when you drag your fingers up or down on your trackpad and let go, it continues scrolling and eventually the acceleration lowers and stops? Well I'd like to make it so it stops instantly **when you put both of your fingers back on the trackpad.** This is a feature on phones and some other operating systems.

How can I achieve this?

Ubuntu 20.04

GNOME DE

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `libinput` added support for "hold gestures" last year, see https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libinput/libinput/-/issues/300. The change had to propagate through GTK, https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/merge_requests/3454, which it did, but only for GTK4 as per https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1568722. Firefox (where I acknowledge the lack of the feature the most) appears to use GTK3 for the GDK APIs it uses. The thread also says that

- hold gestures won't be backported to GTK3, https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1701123
- FF will not be ported to GTK4 in the foreseeable future, https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1701123

so it appears we'll have to wait a quite a bit longer, at least in FF. But the GTK4 apps you listed will likely be equipped to hold-to-cancel kinetic scrolling in the future. I even realize that the "Test Your Settings" view of the Gnome Settings app already supports hold-to-cancel.